# ¿Cómo hacer una consulta a varias colecciones en firebase?

Tags: firebase, sql, nosql, colecciones

estoy tratando de realizar una consulta a varias colecciones en firebase, algo como un inner join de sql, sin embargo he tenido problemas ya que no sé si este servicio de google dispone de tales consultas, espero que puedan ayudarme

Comment: firabase data base es un estilo de base de datos no relacional, por lo que no se pueden realizar muchas operaciones entre "tablas", la base de datos funciona como un arbol, si necesitas hacer un join seguramente estas armando mal la estructura de datos. Este tipo de BD no relacionales suelen diseñarse pensando en hacer un pedido siemple de una rama/subrama y asi obtener los datos, no deberia haber necesidad de un join.

Comment: Entiendo, es que por ejemplo en mongo atlas, se utilizaba una instrucción que se llamaba aggregate que si tú la configurabas bien te sacaba datos de dos colecciones que vos quisieras consultar

Comment: en Mongo tienes una estructura de tablas mucho mas parecida a una relacional, firebase database es un arbol, no existe el join.